# Difference between a wildcard and a named route in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I've been watching several tutorials on Sinatra and can't find the difference, between, say:

```
get "/hey/*/there/*"
```

vs.

```
get "/hey/:first/there/:second"
```

The only difference I see is the way in which the parameters is accessed. So in the first way you access it by:

```
params[:splat][0]
params[:splat[1]
```

while the second way:

```
params[:first]
params[:second]
```

Is a named parameter in Sinatra, just a wildcard to which we give a name? Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not quite the same. Splats can be useful if you want to match an indeterminate number of parameters, rather than a single (named) one. For example:

```
# Will match: "/hey/:first/there/:second"
# Will match: "/hey/*/there/*"
GET /hey/first/there/second

# Won't match: "/hey/:first/there/:second"
# Will match: "/hey/*/there/*"
GET /hey/first/second/there/third/fourth
```